# Does Apple SuperDrive (A1379) have a manual eject?

Tags: optical-drive

I have a stuck DVD in my 'ol [EDIT: external] superdrive, and all the viddys show people [taking them apart](https://youtu.be/4PFz3vm-080)!
I expected to see a small hole in the dust curtain indicating were I can use a paperclip to manually eject the disk. But it's not there. I'm fiddling around with a paperclip on the far right side, but I can't find the lever.

Does the SuperDrive have a manual eject feature?

---

In case you haven't seen this...I have it here somewhere. Ah. Yes. I present to you an Apple Titanium PowerBook G4 optical disk drive. Here you see the visual cue to where you put your paperclip.

[image]

Comment: Apparently those slot-loaders don't have an emergency eject - see https://www.wired.com/2013/02/jammed-dvd-imac/

Comment: That's the answer. No.

Answer (score 1):

It does, but it's as hard to reach as it is to photograph ;)
It's on the left, btw.

[image]

It's slightly below the line of the door, so you need a bent paperclip, curved a bit to reach but not so much that it bends when you push to release the CD mechanism.

You also need three hands… one to hold the door open, one for the torch [flashlight] & a third to do the actual pushing, and of course, as soon as you reach in, your block your own light from the torch.

If it is on an old Mac Pro as this one is, it actually might be easier to take the side off & pull out the optical drive tray, so you can see & reach simultaneously. [There are no screws etc to this, you just pull the assembly out & push back afterwards.]

*Oh… I just realised you meant the external one…*

[image]

I've never actually seen one of those to know the construction - but it looks very much like you're going to have to strip it apart; unless the old trick of holding down the mouse button at boot will force-eject it. [You may need a wired mouse to do this.]

Comment: LOL. Yep. It's the external. I should have added that to the title.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Terminal command:

```
drutil eject external
```

Otherwise, reboot and hold down the mouse or trackpad click at startup.

If the disk is physically stuck (e.g. the drive audibly tries to eject it, but can't), then there is a trick of taking a business card and pushing it into the slit (just a bit!) and sliding it across the opening while it's trying.